# How to extract sheet names from Excel file in R

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I have loaded a workbook into R and read in the worksheets using xlConnect, but I was wondering if there was a way of extracting the names of the sheets perhaps in a vector?

So far my code is:

```
dataIn<-loadWorkbook(file.path(filenames[1],sep=""))
lst = readWorksheet(dataIn, sheet = getSheets(dataIn), startRow=1, startCol=1, header=TRUE)
```

...and I want to extract the sheet names of the sheets in `lst`.

Comment: names(getSheets(dataIn)) will give you list of names of sheets

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are looking for `getSheets`

```
Returns all worksheet names in a workbook.
```

Answer (score 76):

Another really nice package developed by the folks at RStudio is `readxl`. It's easy to get the excel sheet names with the `excel_sheets()` function.

```
library(readxl)
path <- "path/to/your/file.xlsx"
excel_sheets(path = path)
```

Comment: imo this should be the no.1 answer these days

Answer (score 8):

In the "openxlsx" package it would be a command "getSheetNames":

```
library(openxlsx)
path <- "path/to/your/file.xlsx"
getSheetNames(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_Excel_File <- "D:/excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File)
nb_Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()$Count()
sheets_Names <- character(nb_Sheets)

for(i in 1 : nb_Sheets)
{
  sheets_Names[i] <- xlWbk$Sheets(i)$Name()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this after using loadWorkbook, using code from the user's example:

```
dataIn<-loadWorkbook(file.path(filenames[1],sep=""))
names(dataIn)
```

This will print out all the sheets your current workbook object has.