# Is there an R function for extracting sheets names from the all the excel files in my working directory

Tags: r

I have around 300 excel files(with multiple sheets) in my working directory. I use the following code to extract the only the list of files from working directory.

```
 Filesnames <- list.files()
```

But I also need sheet names from these excel files and I need to know from which excel files these sheets are from. For example, Excel 1 has A,B,C sheet names and Excel 2 has X,Y sheet names. When I run a code, I need to get A,B,C from Excel 1 and X,Y from Excel 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944777/how-to-extract-sheet-names-from-excel-file-in-r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract sheet names from Excel file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944777/how-to-extract-sheet-names-from-excel-file-in-r)

Comment: Do I have to install any package before loading workbook ? I am not getting the out put